# How to handle AWS IoT Thing events

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-iot

I've recently signed up to AWS to test out their IoT platform and after setting up a few Things and going through the documentation I still seem to be missing a crucial bit of information - how to wrangle all the information from my Things?

For example if I were to build a web-based application to display the health/status of all the Things and possibly also interact with a specific Thing, what would be the way to go about it?

Do I register a "dummy" thing that also uses the device SDK to pub/sub to the topics?
Do I take whatever data the Things publish and route it to a shared DB for further processing?
Do I create Lambdas that the Things invoke?
Do I create a stand-alone application that uses the general AWS SDK to connect itself to the IoT platform?

To me the last idea sounds the most viable and "preferred" as I would need two-way interaction, not just passive listening to changes in Things, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking your setup might be:

1. IoT device publishes to AWS SQS
2. Some Service (application or lambda) reads from SQS and processes data (e.g. saves it to DynamoDB)

And then to display data

1. Stand alone application reads from DynamoDB and makes data available to users

There are lots of permutations of this. For example your IoT device can [write directly to DynamoDB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/dynamodb-v2-rule.html), then you can process the data from there. I would suggest a better pattern is to write to SQS, as you will have a clean separation between data publishing, processing and storage.

In the first instance I would probably write one application that reads from the SQS, processes the data, stores it in DynamoDB and then provides access to that data for users. A better solution longer term is to have separate systems to process/store the data, and to present that data to users.

Lambda is popular for processing of the device data, as its cost effective (runs only when needed) and scales well. Your data presentation application is probably a traditional webapp running on something like elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Thank you for that, it confirms the direction I was going for. As a follow-up: in your scenario the information flow is one-way - from device to application. What about the situation where I want to give the user control over a device from the webapp?

Comment: When you are writing the user facing application, include the relevant AWS IoT SDK, and that provides methods for you to access devices.